# How to click on button with specific value using selenium (python)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

In the context of using selenium to navigate within a website and select an item with a specified value (e.g. shirt size)

I have tried using the follow two codes which does not work:

1. `size_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='edit-attributes-SIZE-wrapper'][@value='S']").click()`
2. `size_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[text()='S']").click()`

Appended below is a screenshot of how the website looks like.

[Example of item, want to select size "s"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tQbg.png)

The xpath of the size "s" button is `//*[@id="edit-attributes-SIZE-wrapper"]/span/div/span[2]`
The full xpath of size 's' button is `/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/form/div/div[1]/div/span/div/span[2]`

Answer (score 0):

You are using this xpath

```
//input[text()='S']
```

but in HTML I do see that it is `span tag`,

so you will have to change it to:

```
//span[text()='S']
```

or

```
//span[@value='S']
```

and click it like this:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@value='S']"))).click()
    print('Clicked on S button')
except:
    pass
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```